# Alternative of angularjs two function (parsley & reset)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below two function to reset error messages and reset all form fields value.

```
$("#modal_form").parsley().reset();//It only reset error messages not form fields values
$("#modal_form")[0].reset();//It only reset form fields value not message
```

Is there any single method to reset error messages and reset all form fields value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {name:"",age:""};
  $scope.reset = function(){
      $scope.data = {};
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 
 <div >
      <form  name="form">
        
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model = "data.name"  required>    
           
        <input type="text" name="age" ng-model = "data.age" required>
        
        <input type="button" value="reset" ng-click="reset()">
      </form>   
   </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I am having 15 fields, so for that 15 line of code is not ok, I think. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

After using the fields' values you could simply set them all to: ' ' and they will be reset and available for further use.
Same for error messages.