# Reset form on submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-material

I am submitting a form and then making all the field empty but it's not working. Form is getting submitted successfully but the fields are not getting reset. I am using angular-material for styling. Updated controller.

```
 Html

 <form name="myform">
        <md-input-container>
        <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" md-maxlength="20" required="" md-no-asterisk  name="name" ng-model="info.name" md-autofoucs>
        <div ng-messages="myform.name.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The name has to be less than 20 characters long.</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" required md-no-asterisk ng-model="info.phone">
        <div ng-messages="myform.phone.$error">
       <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
       </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="info.email">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="saveit(info)">Save</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-primary">Cancel</md-button>
     </md-input-container>

</form>


 **Function in Controller**
 angular.module('contact', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'templates','ngMessages'])
   .config(['$mdThemingProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider) {

 $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
.primaryPalette('blue')
.accentPalette('orange');

$stateProvider
         .state('home', {
           url: '',
           templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
           controller: 'MainCtrl as vm'

         });

   }]).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav,$mdDialog,$mdToast, contacts) {

     var vm = this;
     $scope.searchText ="";

      $scope.toggleSidenav = function(){
      $mdSidenav('left').open();
    };

    contacts.getall().then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
     $scope.people = response.data;
    });

    $scope.saveit = function(detail, myform){

        if (!detail.name || !detail.phone) { return ;}

          contacts.add({
            name: detail.name,
            phone: detail.phone,
            email: detail.email
          });
          $mdToast.show( 
          $mdToast.simple()
          .content("ContactAdded!")
          .position('top, right')
          .hideDelay(2000)
          );
          $scope.people.push(detail);
        $scope.info = {};
          $scope.myform.$setPristine();
          $scope.myform.$setUntouched();

    };

    $scope.showConfirm = function(ev, person) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Are you sure?')
      .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Please delete it!')
      .cancel('I want to keep it.');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
      contacts.deletethis(person.id).then(function(){
      $mdToast.show( 
        $mdToast.simple()
          .content("Deleted!")
          .position('top, right')
          .hideDelay(2000)
          );

       });
       var index = $scope.people.indexOf(person);
           $scope.people.splice(index,1);
    }, function() {
   $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
   });
   }; });
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087926/alternative-of-angularjs-two-function-parsley-reset/37088011#37088011

Comment: please create plunker for your code.

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: Here github link - https://github.com/sourabh-garg/contactaap.1

Comment: Share your html file and controller code for this view only.

Comment: Nitin, see the controller I have updated it. html page is same.

Comment: You can use the answer from another question right here: [how to reset a form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40267630/4767208)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `$scope` and `this` for controller correctly. You can use `$scope` or `controller as` syntax to bind your scope with view.

I suggest you to read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Update your saveit() function inside controller as below:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $mdToast) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.info = {};

  //your rest the code

  vm.saveit = function() {        
    //do your operations here
    vm.info = {};
  };
});
```

Update your html page as below:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
 <form name="myform">

    <md-input-container>
      <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-maxlength="20" required md-no-asterisk name="name" ng-model="vm.info.name" md-autofoucs>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" required md-no-asterisk ng-model="vm.info.phone">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="vm.info.email">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.saveit()">Save</md-button>
      <md-button class="md-primary">Cancel</md-button>
    </md-input-container>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" ng-model="info.name">
  <input type="text" ng-model="info.phone">
  <input type="text" ng-model="info.email">
</form>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.info = {}; // name, phone, email

  $scope.saveit = function() {
    $scope.info.name = ''; // reset name 
    $scope.info.phone= ''; // reset phone
    $scope.info.email= ''; // reset email

    // reset form and disable error messages
    $scope.myform.$setPristine();
    $scope.myform.$setUntouched();
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give $setPristine to reset the form after saving.

```
$scope.myform.$setPristine();
```

Comment: undefined $scope.myform

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $mdToast) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.info = {};

  vm.saveit = function($event) 
  {        
   var form = angular.element($event.target).parent("form")[0];
   if (form !== undefined) form.reset();
  };
});
```

```html
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
            <form name="myform">

                <md-input-container>
                    <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-maxlength="20" required md-no-asterisk name="name" ng-model="vm.info.name" md-autofoucs>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" required md-no-asterisk ng-model="vm.info.phone">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="vm.info.email">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container>
                    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.saveit($event)">Save</md-button>
                    <md-button class="md-primary">Cancel</md-button>
                </md-input-container>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is missing one line of code to work properly

You can check the answer from another question right here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40267630/4767208