# Angular 1.5 - Clear form after submit

Tags: angularjs

I have read through all of the suggested postings on this, but I can't seem to clear the form fields after I submit.

I am using controller as syntax, but even if I try to use $scope with $setPristine, I still can't make it work.

This SO answer is what I am following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234363/2062075
When I try to copy this code, nothing happens.  No errors, nothing is cleared.

Here is my code:

```
app.controller('HiringRequestCtrl', function ($http) {
    var vm = this; //empty object
    vm.ctrl = {};

    vm.saveChanges = function() {
        //console.log(vm);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/hiringrequest/createPost',
            data: angular.toJson(vm)
        })
            .success(function (response) {
                //great, now reset the form
                vm.ctrl = {};

            })
            .error(function (errorResponse) {

            });

    }
});
```

and my form looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="HiringRequestCtrl as ctrl">
<form id="form" name="ctrl.myForm">
...

    <input type="text" name="proposalName" ng-model="ctrl.proposalName"/>
  <input type="submit" id="saveButton" value="Submit" class="button" ng-click="ctrl.saveChanges()" />
  ...  

</form>
</div>
```

I would really prefer not to use $scope.

Comment: when you are using "ui-router" for navigation, easiest way is to reload the current state with "$state.reload("myStatePathToThisForm");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some fundamental issues with the way you've structured this. I think your use of `vm.ctrl` and then also `ng-controller="HiringRequestCtrl as ctrl"` is confusing you. Below are my recommended [untested] changes. (I would also suggest moving the `$http` stuff into a service and using `.then()` and `.catch()` because `.success()` and `.error()` are deprecated).

*Controller*

```
.controller('HiringRequestCtrl', function($http) {
    var vm = this; // self-referencing local variable required for when promise resolves
    vm.model = {};

    vm.saveChanges = function() {
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/hiringrequest/createPost',
                data: angular.toJson(vm.model)
            })
            .success(function(response) {
                //great, now reset the form
                vm.model = {}; // this resets the model
                vm.myForm.$setPristine(); // this resets the form itself
            })
            .error(function(errorResponse) {});
    }
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="HiringRequestCtrl as ctrl">
    <form id="form" name="ctrl.myForm" ng-submit="ctrl.saveChanges()" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="proposalName" ng-model="ctrl.model.proposalName" />
        <input type="submit" id="saveButton" value="Submit" class="button" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Update**
*Service*

```
.service('hiringService', function($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.createPost = function(model) {
        return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/hiringrequest/createPost',
                    data: angular.toJson(model)
                });
    }
    return service;
}
```

*Controller*

```
.controller('HiringRequestCtrl', function(hiringService) {
    vm.saveChanges = function() {
        hiringService.createPost(model)
            .then(function(response) {
                // if you need to work with the returned data access using response.data
                vm.model = {}; // this resets the model
                vm.myForm.$setPristine(); // this resets the form itself
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // handle errors
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It was really helpful to get a basic recipe (including what is deprecated, best practice ,etc) for Angular.    Thanks for your help.  
Off topic - How do you suggest I move the $http to a service?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you might use a service - this makes it available to other controllers and keeps your controller code focused on being the link between model and view.

Comment: Concise and well written.  Thanks again Lex.

Comment: Hello, this works fine as long as you don't have required fields. With required fields, you will keep on getting ng-invalid-required. Any idea how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: @Bill `ng-invalid` and `ng-invalid-required` will be set whenever the input has the `required` attribute and doesn't contain data. If you are looking to condition the display of an error message (for example) you should check `formName.formElement.$touched` (or `formName.formElement.$dirty` depending on your needs) in addition to `formName.formElement.$invalid`. This will allow you to only show the error message when the user has actually moved through the input and not entered a required value. Does that address the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: Thanks @Lex. It makes more sense now.