# Clear form using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**Problem:** I am unable to clear the fields of the form completely.

Let me be more specific. When I go to the console, it appears that the previous entries are still present even though the reset button has been selected.

I have done the following in the form. I have a submit button and a reset button.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

        <!---<div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>--->
                <!---<option disabled="disabledvalue=""></option>---><!---<option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option>
            </select>--->
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
                     <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                      <cfoutput query="SpFind">
                       <option value=#ProviderSpecialty#>#ProviderSpecialty#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                <option selected="selected" value="">City</option>
                     <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                      <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                       <option value=#city#>#city#</option>

                       <!---<option ng-selected="{{searchParam.City==#city#?true:false}} value=#city#>#city#</option>--->
                    </cfoutput> 
            </select>

        <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities" value="{{c.City}}">{{c.City}}</option> </select>--->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!---<div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
                <div class="form-group widthLanguage">


                <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                 <cfoutput query="Languages">
                      <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>



                  <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
                  </select>--->
                </div>
            </div>--->

            <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
                <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="hrDoctor" />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance">
                        <!---<option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">Miles</option>--->
                            <option selected="disabled" value=""></option>
                            <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
                            <!---<option selected="disabled" value=""></option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="15">15</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>---> 
                        </select>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField(); overlayDisplayButton();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
            <div style="margin-top:10pt"><button type="reset" class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the following script to reset the form:

```
    $scope.reset = function(form) {
    form.$setPristine();
    form.$setUntouched();
};
```

What am I missing to reset the form completely?

Comment: what is your form object?

Comment: That can't be the *entire* form....  Without seeing what you are trying to reset, trying to figure out why it won't reset would just be a blind guess.  besides the fact that you are expecting a `form` object in your function, but aren't passing one from your button click.....

Comment: @Claies sorry here is the complete form

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604403/how-do-i-clear-or-reset-data-in-a-form-in-angularjs

Comment: so just init `$scope.searchParam = {}` to clear form.

Comment: @Hadi :  I have done the folloiwng ng-click="searchParam = {}" which clear the value but when I try to select a new field and search, whatever data was displayed before remains

Answer (score 0):

This should be your reset function:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.searchParam = {};
    $scope.providerSearch.$setPristine();
    $scope.providerSearch.$setUntouched();
};
```

where `providerSearch` is a form name.